# How to add a filter conditionally based on page related Conditional Tags

Tags: plugins, filters, conditional-tags

I am developing a WordPress plugin and can't conditionally add filters based on the conditional tags.

This is my code:

```
add_Action('init', 'determine_location');

function determine_location() {
$d = get_option('display_locations'); //this is a checkbox field in the plugins settings with 7 options
    if (isset($d)) {
        if ($d[0] == 'home') {
            if (is_home()) {
                add_filter('the_excerpt', 'insert_buttons_to_post_top');
                add_filter('the_content', 'insert_buttons_to_post_top');
            }
        } else if ($d == 'post' || $d == 'post') {
            if (is_single()) {
                add_filter('the_content', 'insert_buttons_to_post_top');
            }
        } else if ($d[0] == 'page' || $d == 'page' || $d == 'page') {
            if (is_page()) {
                add_filter('the_content', 'insert_buttons_to_post_top');
            }
        } else if ($d[0] == 'category' || $d[1] == 'category' || $d[2] == 'category' || $d[3] == 'category') {
            if (is_category()) {
                add_filter('the_excerpt', 'insert_buttons_to_post_top');
                add_filter('the_content', 'insert_buttons_to_post_top');
            }
        } else if ($d[0] == 'tag' || $d[1] == 'tag' || $d[2] == 'tag' || $d[3] == 'tag' || $d[4] == 'tag') {
            if (is_tag()) {
                add_filter('the_excerpt', 'insert_buttons_to_post_top');
                add_filter('the_content', 'insert_buttons_to_post_top');
            }
        } else if ($d[0] == 'archive' || $d[1] == 'archive' || $d[2] == 'archive' || $d[3] == 'archive' || $d[4] == 'archive' || $d[5] == 'archive') {
            if (is_archive()) {
                add_filter('the_excerpt', 'insert_buttons_to_post_top');
                add_filter('the_content', 'insert_buttons_to_post_top');
            }
        }
    }
```

}

```
function insert_buttons_to_post_top(){
   return "<div>Output</div>"
}
```

Currently this code shows no output. What is wrong here?

Comment: Can you show us the scope where you are using the conditional tags? Are they inside an action hook? If so, which one?

Comment: Just updated the question. It is in the **init** hook

Comment: It should be `add_action`, not `add_Action`

Answer (score -1):

The conditional tags must be run after WP object is set up. The wp action hook is the first one where you can use these conditionals safely. See the [warning message in the conditional tags documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#Introduction).

So, you should hook into `wp` action or later event; also, the correct function name is `add_action`, not `add_Action`:

```
add_action('wp', 'determine_location');
```